# Simpler boolean truth table?

Tags: java

I'm doing a [CodingBat exercise](http://codingbat.com/prob/p181646) and would like to learn to write code in the most efficient way. On this exercise, I was just wondering if there's a shorter way to write this code.

```
monkeyTrouble(true, true) → true
monkeyTrouble(false, false) → true
monkeyTrouble(true, false) → false
```

```
public boolean monkeyTrouble(boolean aSmile, boolean bSmile) {

  if (aSmile && bSmile) {
      return true;
  }

  if (!aSmile && !bSmile) {
      return true;
  }

  return false; 

}
```

Comment: there is "Show Solution" button that shows 3 solutions on the page you linked

Answer (score 26):

Sometimes it is easy to forget that the simplest logical constructs like boolean are comparable with the `==` operator, and that, in Java, `(false == false)` is `true`.

With this in mind, your code could become:

```
public boolean monkeyTrouble(boolean aSmile, boolean bSmile) {
    return aSmile == bSmile;
}
```

---

It may be easier to see how to get there if you first transform your original code into

```
public boolean monkeyTrouble(boolean aSmile, boolean bSmile) {
    if ((aSmile && bSmile) || (!aSmile && !bSmile)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

… which could become

```
public boolean monkeyTrouble(boolean aSmile, boolean bSmile) {
    return (aSmile && bSmile) || (!aSmile && !bSmile);
}
```

From there, you may come to the realization that "both true or both false" is equivalent to "both the same".

---

Here is a verification of the output:

```
public static boolean monkeyTrouble(boolean aSmile, boolean bSmile) {
    return aSmile == bSmile;
}

private static void testTruth(boolean a, boolean b) {
    System.out.printf("monkeyTrouble(%s, %s) = %s\n", a, b, monkeyTrouble(a, b));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    testTruth(true, true);
    testTruth(true, false);
    testTruth(false, true);
    testTruth(false, false);
}
```

This produces:

```
monkeyTrouble(true, true) = true
monkeyTrouble(true, false) = false
monkeyTrouble(false, true) = false
monkeyTrouble(false, false) = true
```

Comment: But there are two conditions there. The one states that if both monkeys are smiling or if neither of them are smiling, return 'true'. So wouldn't simply making aSmile == bSmile ignore those two conditions?

Comment: if both are smiling then `aSmile == bSmile` is `true == true`, and that is `true`. If neither are smiling then `aSmile == bSmile` is `false == false`, and that resolves to `true`. If only one is smiling, then `aSmile == bSmile` is `false == true`, and that resolves to `false`.

Comment: Trust me, I'm a monkey, and I know `monkeyTrouble()` ;-)

Comment: *truth of false and false is true* - doesn't that sound like monkey business? `(false && false) == false` returns `true`, no? Then false *and* false is... false.

Comment: @retailcoder : big difference between `false == false` and `false && false`.... ;-)

Comment: @200 fixed it :)

Answer (score 11):

This is the **exclusive-or** *(or XOR)* condition negated.

You can simply do this:

```
public boolean monkeyTrouble(boolean aSmile, boolean bSmile) {
    return !(aSmile ^ bSmile);
}
```

or, as it is so simply, you can use it in your code without the function.

---

Explanation of **XOR** operator `^`:

```
a   ^    b     =   c

1        0         1
0        1         1
0        0         0
1        1         0
```

Comment: The negation of XOR is also known as [XNOR](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/XNOR.html).

Comment: Wrong precedence there.

Comment: Shouldn't this be: `!(aSmile ^ bSmile)`?

Comment: @WayneConrad, you are right, Its corrected! It also works the other way, but this is the correct one, thanks.